# Pipe Soundstretch for loop results

Tags: linux, batch-processing

How can I pipe the information about BPM scan using soundstretch using a for loop?

I tried this:

```
for f in *.wav ; do soundstretch "$f" -bpm ; done >> Data
```

It shows the data on the terminal but it doesn't save it to the file.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found it:

```
for f in *.wav ; do soundstretch "$f" -bpm ; done 2> Data
```